# Transforming Database in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Not sure if it's even possible but I'm using Access 2010 and have the following table

```
> Reference|| Start Date || Month 1 || Month 2 || Month 3 || month N 
> 123      || 01/02/2012 || 50      || 50      || 70      || 50 321     
> 321      || 12/05/2012 || 60      || 40      || 90      || 0
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to transform this into a table of

```
Reference || Start date || January 12 || February 12 || March 12 || April 12 || May 12 ||..
123       || 01/02/2012 || 0          || 50          || 50       || 70       || 50     ||
321       || 12/05/2012 || 0          || 0           || 0        || 0        || 60     ||
```

Is this possible using Access, given that Month 1 has no relation to January 12, though it can be derived from the Start DAate

REgards
Maudise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a UNION query to "un-pivot" your data:

```
SELECT Reference, [Start Date], 0 AS [Month Offset], [Month 1] AS Qty
FROM TableN
UNION ALL
SELECT Reference, [Start Date], 1 AS [Month Offset], [Month 2] AS Qty
FROM TableN
UNION ALL
SELECT Reference, [Start Date], 2 AS [Month Offset], [Month 3] AS Qty
FROM TableN
UNION ALL
SELECT Reference, [Start Date], 3 AS [Month Offset], [Month 4] AS Qty
FROM TableN
```

Repeat the UNION ALL pattern until you have included all of the [Month N] fields in the original table. Save this query as [QtyByMonth]. The result should look like this

```
Reference  Start Date  Month Offset  Qty
---------  ----------  ------------  ---
123        2012-02-01             0   50
321        2012-05-12             0   60
123        2012-02-01             1   50
321        2012-05-12             1   40
123        2012-02-01             2   70
321        2012-05-12             2   90
123        2012-02-01             3   50
321        2012-05-12             3    0
```

Now create a query that creates the base from which you will perform your crosstab by month:

```
SELECT 
    Reference, 
    [Start Date], 
    DateAdd("m", [Month Offset], DateSerial(Year([Start Date]), Month([Start Date]), 1)) AS [FirstOfMonth],
    Qty
FROM QtyByMonth
```

...returning...

```
Reference  Start Date  FirstOfMonth  Qty
---------  ----------  ------------  ---
123        2012-02-01  2012-02-01     50
321        2012-05-12  2012-05-01     60
123        2012-02-01  2012-03-01     50
321        2012-05-12  2012-06-01     40
123        2012-02-01  2012-04-01     70
321        2012-05-12  2012-07-01     90
123        2012-02-01  2012-05-01     50
321        2012-05-12  2012-08-01      0
```

Save that query as [BasisForXtab]. Now build your crosstab based on that...

```
TRANSFORM Sum(BasisForXtab.Qty) AS SumOfQty
SELECT BasisForXtab.Reference, BasisForXtab.[Start Date]
FROM BasisForXtab
GROUP BY BasisForXtab.Reference, BasisForXtab.[Start Date]
PIVOT Format([FirstOfMonth],"yyyy-MM");
```

...returning...

```
Reference  Start Date  2012-02  2012-03  2012-04  2012-05  2012-06  2012-07  2012-08
---------  ----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
123        2012-02-01       50       50       70       50                           
321        2012-05-12                                  60       40       90        0
```

Comment: I had to take UNION ALL out of each level in the original query and replace with just UNION in excel but that seemed to solve the problem.